# Necessary and sufficient conditions for $\mbox{trace}(A^{-1/2}e^{-tB} (AB+BA) e^{-tB}A^{-1/2}) \ge 0$ for all $t$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, traces

Let $A$ and $B$ be positive-definite matrices of the same size. For any $t \ge 0$, define
$$
u(t) := \mbox{trace}(A^{-1/2}e^{-tB} (AB+BA) e^{-tB}A^{-1/2}).
$$

> **Question.** What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ and $B$, such that $u(t) \ge 0$ for all $t \ge 0$ ?

**Note.** A sufficient condition is that $A$ and $B$ commute, or more generally, that $AB+BA$ is positive-semidefinite.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by positive definite? If $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian and positive definite in the sense $v^\dagger A v > 0$, then one can construct positive definite $\sqrt{A}$. $AB = \sqrt{A} \sqrt{A} B$ has the same eigenvalues as $\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A}$ which is manifestly positive definite. Sums of positive definite matrices are also positive definite. Thus $AB + BA$ is always positive definite.

Comment: @user196574 : 
counterexample to your claim :

$A=
\biggl(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{matrix}  \biggr)$ , $B=
\biggl(\begin{matrix}
1.01 & 1 \\
1 & 1.01
\end{matrix}  \biggr)$

Comment: @jjcale Thanks, I see where I went wrong. It's true $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues as $\sqrt{A} B \sqrt{A}$, which are indeed positive. However, these matrices don't obey the $v^\dagger A v > 0$ condition, which would be sufficient for their sum $AB+BA$ to still be positive. That is, as in jjcale's example, $AB+BA$ need not have only positive eigenvalues. I hadn't appreciated this before that the Hermitian part of a matrix with positive eigenvalues need not have positive eigenvalues, but I see it's true for actually many matrices!